# Cannot pass environment variables via Maven command in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, environment-variables

I am trying to run my Spring Boot app using maven command and pass some environment variables to this command. Normally, I create some definition on README.md for running application by describing the menus on IntelliJ, but I think it is much better to describe and let users to run or debug app via maven command.

On the other hand, there may be an alternative way to run or debug Spring Boot app via Spring commands e.g. `spring-boot:run`. In each case, could you please give an example for:

- run / debug app via maven commands by passing environment variables
- run / debug app via maven by READING environment variables from .env file

I also read [Running your Application with Maven](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#run), but could not see debug and reading variables from environment file.

Also, could not understand the difference between these:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments=...

mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments=...
```

Here is my `.env` file; I also copy it and keep as `.env-dev` in case dev profile reads from dev version. Both of them has the following content:

```
DB_NAME=demo
DB_USERNAME=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=pass
JWT_SECRET=appSecretKey
```

Comment: I have developed my own [IntelliJ plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/18734-springboot-patcher) to be able to launch spring-boot applications via green "play button" and configure launch parameters in pom.xml/settings.xml. Another option is to share run configurations in IntelliJ: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration.html#share-configurations

Comment: AndreyB.Panfilov I actually use IntelliJ, but I want to use maven at this time and it is really strange that no one else have no idea except from @JavaLearner1. I tried many examples, but even not running by passing parameters that I normally can with Run configuration.

Comment: I tried this command, but still gives password error. I use "dev" in IntelliJ, I don't see any problem with this command: `mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-Xdebug" -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=dev 
-Dspring-boot.run.arguments="'DB_NAME=demo','DB_USERNAME=postgres',DB_PASSWORD=pass','JWT_SECRET=appSecretKey'"`

Comment: Can you try removing the leading hyphens (-) and add spaces between properties instead of the comma (,) only for the run.arguments section. So something like `-Dspring-boot.run.arguments="DB_NAME=demo DB_USERNAME=postgres DB_PASSWORD=pass JWT_SECRET=appSecretKey"`

Comment: Do you mean `mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-Xdebug" -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=dev 
-Dspring-boot.run.arguments="DB_NAME=demo DB_USERNAME=postgres DB_PASSWORD=pass JWT_SECRET=appSecretKey"` ? I tried it and still get "FATAL: password authentication failed for user "${DB_USERNAME}"". Any idea?

Comment: Actually, I normally use these parameters (`DB_NAME=demo DB_USERNAME=postgres DB_PASSWORD=pass JWT_SECRET=appSecretKey`) as Environment Variables in IntelliJ. But ı am not sure if I should convert them as Run argument.

Comment: Can you share where are you using ${DB_USERNAME}? Is it in your application.properties file?

Comment: No, it is in `.env` file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252531/discussion-between-ameenhere-and-carol).

Comment: But I could not understand the relation with the `.env` files. Because, in here we are trying to pass these values via command. Of course we can also read from file, but I am not sure if we can read while we pass these variables via command

Answer (score 0):

-Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments
JVM arguments are used to specify arguments that are passed directly to JVM (Java Virtual Machine). These arguments control the **behavior of JVM itself rather than the Spring Boot Application.**
Ex: -Xmx, -XX:+UseG1GC

-Dspring-boot.run.arguments
Arguments are used to specify the arguments that are passed to the Spring Boot application itself. These arguments configure the **behavior of Spring Boot application or provide inputs to it.**
Ex: --server.port

Comment: Good explanation, thanks. Then I should use the second one, but when I try `mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments=--DB_NAME=demo,--DB_USERNAME=postgres,--DB_PASSWORD=pass,--JWT_SECRET=appSecretKey 
-Dspring-boot.run.profiles=local,dev` I get "FATAL: password authentication failed for user "${DB_USERNAME}" error. Any idea?

Comment: Also, can I read environment variables from `.env` file instead of passing via command?

Comment: This is also not working :( `mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-DB_NAME=demo,-DB_USERNAME=postgres,-DB_PASSWORD=pass,-JWT_SECRET=appSecretKey"`

Comment: @Carol From the error - FATAL: password authentication failed for user "${DB_USERNAME}..seems like password issue..can you try to login to db directly?

Comment: I retried again and can connect with the same credentials. Are you sure that the app read variables from this maven command? Because I though the displayed message would be "demo" instead of "${DB_USERNAME}" if it was read. Any idea?

Comment: At last step I tried `mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments="--DB_NAME=demo --DB_USERNAME=postgres --DB_PASSWORD=pass --JWT_SECRET=appSecretKey"`, but the app still tries to read from application.properties file